# Looking for a way to shorten my code

Tags: c#, loops

This is my code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        Console.Write("How many tests would you like to do? 1 to 10: ");

        int tests = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine();

    }
```

can someone help me out with my code please? i have no idea what im doing

Thanks

Comment: organize all `count2..count12` into a *collection*, say, `int[] count` - array

Comment: i'm curious at why you started at `count2` My OCD went off all over the place

Comment: @TheGeneral because you can't score 0 or 1 on 2 regular D6 dice

Comment: Review of functional code is more appropriate on [codereview.se].

Comment: Re the edit; the purpose of Stack Overflow is not just to help the person asking, but also: to leave artefacts - code that can help other people in the future. Destroying the question makes that much harder, and is frankly disappointing. I'm tempted to revert the edit, but: [the original remains available](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50270127/1).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make an array `int[] counts = new int[13]` and just use `counts[total]++;`; at the end, loop over it:

```
for(int i = 2 ; i <= 12 ; i++)
    // etc
```

(note: you *could* use an array of 11 items and constantly handle the off-by-two, but... it probably isn't worth it)

---

Something like:

```
static void Main()
{

    Console.WriteLine("Investigation 1");
    Console.WriteLine("===============");
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.Write("How many sets of tests? 1 to 10: ");

    int sets = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine();

    Random r = new Random();
    int[] counts = new int[13];

    for (int ctr = 0; ctr < 36 * sets; ctr++)
    {
        int a = r.Next(1, 7), b = r.Next(1, 7), total = a + b;
        Console.WriteLine($"Roll {(ctr + 1)}: {a} + {b} = {total}");
        counts[total]++;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("=======================");
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Total  Expected  Actual");
    Console.WriteLine("=====  ========  ======");

    for(int i = 2; i <= 12; i++)
    {
        var expected = sets * (6 - Math.Abs(7 - i));
        Console.WriteLine($"  {i}        {expected}        {counts[i]}");
    }
}
```

---

For a histogram:

```
var maxCount = counts.Max(); // needs "using System.Linq;" at the top
for (int i = 2; i <= 12; i++)
{
    var width = ((Console.WindowWidth - 10) * counts[i]) / maxCount; // make it proportional
    Console.WriteLine($"{i}\t{new string('*', width)}");
}
```

Comment: Okay, I tried putting your code into my first FOR loop but when doing that my lower half of the code has stopped working and is now reading an error. It doesn't recognise "counts" in the current context. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: And if i have it outside of the loop, the "total" becomes invaild and i cant use that :(

Comment: @John 2 secs... I'll hack it together#

Comment: AMAZING!! Thank you lots and lots, but... I have another request if you would be able to help? Is there a way to create a bar graph using "*"?

Comment: Thank you, worked well :) you just saved me hours of strain haha